# Alternative to overiding static in java

Tags: java, inheritance, static, abstract

I was wondering: what would be the best way to fit an attribute to a class which is part of a large inheritance structure. I wanted to make an abstract static method which each class would override but after a quick google that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

I could make it an instance method but it really is a class level specification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you've found, static polymorphism doesn't exist in Java.  What is the overall goal?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to do with this static method? Maybe we can find an alternative solution.

Comment: To be more specific: we're dealing with a boolean value which i need to be able to query for an object of each class specifically. So I think i answered my own question: I should make it an instance method.

Comment: just for each object of the same class the value is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you create an abstract method, just as you have thought of, and let this method be implemented in terms of static variables in each class.

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract String getValue();
}

class A extends Base {

    static String aValue = "From A";

    String getValue() {
        return aValue;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    static String bValue = "From B";

    String getValue() {
        return bValue;
    }
}
```

It requires a little bit more boiler plate in each class, than just a field declaration, but I believe it is hard to do anything about that.