# static inheritance: is it possible? Are there better solutions?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Consider this example (warning-very bad code):

```
public abstract class A {

    static float foo;

    public static void loadfoo(float incomingfoo) {
        foo = incomingfoo;
    }
    public static void displayfoo() {
        System.out.println("your foo is" +foo);
    }

}
```

Class B extends Class A

```
public class B extends A {

    static float foo;

    //@Override (overide is not allowed for static methods.  dis is a problem...)
    public static void loadfoo(float incomingfoo){
        foo = incomingfoo;
    }
}
```

Class C is pretty much the same as B

```
public class C extends A {
    static float foo;

    //@Override 
    public static void loadfoo(float incomingfoo) {
        //I would like  a different static variable loaded into this class using this method
        foo = incomingfoo;
    }
}
```

finally the main Class runs the thing

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String whatever[]){
        B.loadfoo(5);
        C.loadfoo(8);
        B.displayfoo();
        C.displayfoo();
    }
}
```

so the output of this is :

```
your foo is0.0
your foo is0.0
```

and I am aware this is because the `displayfoo` class reference the static foo in Class A, so please disregard this. I assume I have now been specific enough about describing my problem and goal.  solutions anyone?

Edit: I feel like an idiot I completely forgot to actually state what I wanted to accomplish, but really all I want is for B and C to have there own static variables loaded into them without altering A's variable, which should be the default.

Comment: I don't see a question here? Could you be more specific as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you have not seen it already, I suggest that you review [the following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java) post.

Comment: No, you have been specific enough about describing a well-known situation wherein static methods are not subject to polymorphism. But what is your problem? What do you want to achieve? What is your goal?

Comment: Have you considered using _singleton_ instances instead of calling static methods?

Comment: It seems that first you want to load the values using `loadfoo` to `foo` and then display the value of that `foo` using the `displayfoo` method. Well, I don't think there is anyway to do it using static methods. But You can do the same by making `displayfoo()` method abstract and overriding the same in the subclasses `B` and `C`.

Comment: `static` methods almost always sucks. Throw it away and use proper OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need static access to two stateful objects with the same structure. In this case, an enum might be a solution:

```
public enum A {
  B, C;

  private float foo;
  // getter and (optional) setter for foo here

  public void displayFoo() { System.out.println("This foo  is " + foo); }
}
```

This way you can still access your object statically, but don't need to duplicate anything else:

```
A.B.setFoo(5);
A.C.setFoo(8);
A.B.displayFoo(); // 5
A.C.displayFoo(); // 8
```

If you then need a static default, I would make it a method on A:

```
enum A {
  A getDefault() { return A.B; }
}

A.getDefault().displayFoo();
```

Comment: very creative Idea.  It's interesting you say this as this was my original idea, but then I scrapped it because I am not very familiar with Enums, however I do believe this is a very valid solution, and I will quite likely end up using this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that first you want to load the values using `loadfoo` to `foo` and then display the value of that `foo` using the `displayfoo` method. Well, I don't think there is anyway to do it using static methods.You can do this by making `displayfoo()` method abstract and overriding the same in the subclasses `B` and `C`.

Here is the code:

```
abstract class A {
     float foo;
     public void loadfoo(float incomingfoo){
        foo = incomingfoo;
     }
     public abstract void displayfoo();
}

class B extends A{
    @Override 
    public void loadfoo(float incomingfoo){
        foo = incomingfoo;
    }
    @Override
    public void displayfoo(){
        System.out.println("foo is " + foo);
    }
}

class C extends A{
    @Override 
    public void loadfoo(float incomingfoo){
        this.foo = incomingfoo;
    }
    @Override
    public void displayfoo(){
        System.out.println("foo is " + foo);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String whatever[]){
         B b = new B();
         C c = new C();
         b.loadfoo(5);
         c.loadfoo(5);
         b.displayfoo();
         c.displayfoo();
    }
}
```

You can also check the same kind of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718004/alternative-to-overiding-static-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Static methods should be used by static method access and not by object instance. It's not supposed to be virtual because it's not belong to the object.

- If you call `B.loadfoo()` then a method of B class is called.
- If you call `C.loadfoo()` then a method of C class is called.
- You cannot call a static method if it doesn't exist in the class.

There's no point to use static methods if you want to use polimorphism.